# Handling multiple parameter expansions in one statment in Bash

Tags: bash

**A.** [This bash guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters) says that you cannot use multiple parameter expansions in the same statement. However, observe the following example:

```
$ k="$(( 1 + 1 ))"
$ echo "$(( $k + 2 ))"
4
```

So apparently you can (unquoted `$k`). How can can I even avoid nesting the `$k` in this example?

**B.** Furthermore, the guide advises to always quote parameter expansions, but how am I supposed to quote `$k` in that example?

In any case, the following raises a syntax error:
`echo "$(( "$k" + 2 ))"`
as well as
`echo "$(( \"$k\" + 2 ))"`

However I"m guessing that the guide meant that only the outer parameter expansion has to be quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arithmetic expansion is not parameter expansion. See `man bash`:

> $((expression))
>
> The expression is treated as if it were within double quotes, but a double quote inside the parentheses  is  not  treated  specially.   All  tokens in the expression undergo parameter expansion, string expansion, command substitution, and quote  removal.   Arithmetic  expansions may be nested.

Comment: Excellent answer, straight from the most authoritative documentation. Thanks!